# Is this a manifold with boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I am new to differential geometry/manifolds. I have two questions:

1) Are two disks tangentially touching each other a manifold with boundary. ie: is this set a manifold with boundary

$$\{(x,y):(x-1)^2+y^2\leq 1\} \cup \{(x,y):(x+1)^2+y^2\leq 1 \}$$

2) If this isn't a manifold with boundary, is there some other special term for the above in differential geometry?

Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not a manifold with boundary; no, there is no special name for such spaces. Feel free to invent your own terminology if you have to deal with such spaces on a regular basis.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Immersed submanifold with boundary?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland: This would not be a good terminology since it is not the image of an immersion of a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @SeleneAuckland: More precisely, ... of a connected manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a manifold with boundary because the point $(0,0)$ (which you can check is a boundary point) does not have a neighborhood homeomorphic to the half disk $\{(x,y) \mid x^2+y^2 < 1, x\geq 0\}$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $x \ge 0$ ?

Comment: @AmeetSharma Yes, thank you.

Comment: Immersed submanifold with boundary?